# I want to calculate the current download speed of network while playing videos in flutter

Tags: flutter, download-speed

I am using video_player_flutter_master for playing videos but i also want to show the download speed of the network just like Traffic State Api in android for getting received bytes. I am not able to getting this in flutter only plugin available for checking network connection.

Comment: Why not use something like that: https://pub.dev/packages/internet_speed_test ? Otherwise you can always download a file of fixed size and measure the time to get a rough estimate.

Comment: Thanks i saw it but it gives me only speed for some time but my work around is different